# Circular linked list of integers

Tags: java, optimization, linked-list, circular-list

I'm looking for a review paying special attention as to whether the code can be optimized in the form of number of variables used, especially for the `delete()` method.

```
public class circularLL {

    Node start;
    Node last;

    circularLL()
    {
        start=null;
        last=null;
    }

    class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int datanew)
        {
            data=datanew;
        }
        public void setNext(Node n)
        {
            next=n;
        }
        public Node getNext()
        {
            return next;
        }
        public void setData(int datanew)
        {
            data=datanew;
        }
        public int getData()
        {
            return data;
        }
    }

    public void insert(int datanew)
    {
        Node p=new Node(datanew);
        if(start==null)
        {
            start=p;
            last=p;
            p.setNext(p);
        }
        else
        {
            last.setNext(p);
            last=last.getNext();
            last.setNext(start);
        }
    }
    public void delete(int datanew)
    {
        Node temp=start;
        Node temp1=start;
        Node previous=null;
        Node previous1=null;
        if(last.getData()==datanew)
        {
            while(temp1.getData()!=datanew)
            {
                previous1=temp1;
                temp1=temp1.getNext();
            }
            previous1.setNext(temp.getNext());
            last=previous1;
        }
        while(temp.getData()!=datanew)
        {
            previous=temp;
            temp=temp.getNext();
        }
        previous.setNext(temp.getNext());
    }

    public void display() {
        int count = 0;

        if(start == null) {
            System.out.println("\n List is empty !!");
        } else {
            Node temp = start;

            while(temp.getNext() != last) {
                System.out.println("count("+count+") , node value="+temp.getData());
                count++;
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            System.out.println("count("+count+") , node value="+temp.getData());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        circularLL ll=new circularLL();
        ll.insert(40);
        ll.insert(20);
        ll.insert(22);
        ll.insert(15);
        ll.insert(16);
        ll.insert(35);
        ll.insert(40);
        ll.insert(38);
        ll.delete(22);
        ll.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: You would get more reviews if you provide more information about this piece of code.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not a big algorithms/data structures guy, but the only thing that caught my attention was the `delete` function. Is there a reason that `delete` uses data to identify the node, as opposed to just taking in the `Node` object you want to delete? It seems like that could get hairy if two nodes have the same data (which happens in `main`).

Besides that, there are a few comments I have in general about the code. Most of the following is fairly standard code format type stuff, but I think it's worth saying it as many times as possible.

**Formatting**

It's fairly minor, it helps to make sure there's an empty line between methods.

Also, I know some feel differently, but my preference about operators is that they have spaces on either side. `data=datanew` vs `data = datanew`.

**Naming**

In Java, the convention is that class names start with a capital letter, so `circularLL` should be `CircularLL`. Even better, it should really be something more descriptive like `CircularLinkedList`.

Besides that, names of methods, members, variables, etc should follow lowerCamelCase. So, `datanew` becomes `dataNew`, but I would personally call it `newData`.

In `delete`, avoid variable names like `temp1` and `previous1`. With the number of variables and how they're named, you're starting to enter mental-juggling territory. What I mean by that is that as I read through the code, I have to keep reading back through the code to remember what a variable does because its name isn't descriptive enough.

**Etc**

I don't have too much else to say, but I would consider breaking this code out into two or three files. I would make a new class with `main` to separate the linked list from what's using it, and I might put `Node` in its own class.

Sorry I couldn't help out more with the efficiency/number of variables issue, but you don't seem to be doing anything too crazy, and like I said before, data structures and algorithms aren't my strong suit. Just thought I'd throw in my two cents.

Comment: Oh, just saw that you indented it, I'll take that out.

Comment: +1 for formatting.  The code looks closer to C code instead of java.  While old, the code conventions from Sun is pretty widely accepted: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 3):

Generics would be quite useful here, because your `List` only works with `integers`, so your classes could be reworked to take type parameters

```
 public class CircularLL<T>{

 Node<T> start;
 Node<T> last;

 class Node<T>{
  T data;
  public void setData(T datanew)
  {
    data= datanew;
  }
  public T getData()
  {
    return data;
  }
  ....
 }

}
```

and now you create Lists of different types.

```
  CircularLL<Integer> list = new CircularLL<Integer>();
  CircularLL<String> list = new CircularLL<String>();
```

in Java 7 you got type `inference`

```
  CircularLL<Integer> list = new CircularLL<>();
```

Please note, that CircularLL is not the best name for this class, I would call it `CircularLinkedList` instead.

One more thing, initialising instance variables to `null` is useless because it's done by default.